# How to define parameters in a generate block and access them outside?

Tags: parameters, verilog, modelsim

I want to define some local parameters whose values are decided by a parameter assigned outside this module. Here, I use a generate block. Just like the following:

```
module doppler_fft_cluster # (
  parameter CORE_TYPE = "DOPPLER_FFT_D0"
) (
  clk, rst_,
  i_tvalid, i_tdata, i_tready, i_tlast
  // and more ports
);

input clk;
input rst_;

generate
  case (CORE_TYPE)
    "DOPPLER_FFT_D0": begin
      localparam FFT_XN_DATA_WIDTH = 42;
      localparam FFT_XK_DATA_WIDTH = 66;
      localparam FFT_LENGTH = 2048;
    end
    "DOPPLER_FFT_D1": begin
      localparam FFT_XN_DATA_WIDTH = 64;
      localparam FFT_XK_DATA_WIDTH = 66;
      localparam FFT_LENGTH = 512;
    end
  endcase
endgenerate

input  i_tvalid;
input  i_tdata;
output i_tready;
input  i_tlast;
input  [FFT_XN_DATA_WIDTH-1:0] i_tdata;  // Boom!

// ... ...

endmodule
```

I have tried to simulate this module using ModelSim, but it says those local parameters undefined.

```
Error: ./demo.v(31): (vlog-2730) Undefined variable: 'FFT_XN_DATA_WIDTH'.
```

It seems like this localparams cannot enter the module-level scope.

So, how can I access them under module-level? Or, is there any other way to implement something like this?

**UPDATE 0616**

I fianlly choose Ehab Ibrahim's method, because my project requires Xilinx ISE, or XST synthesizer, which cannot accept `parameter` or `localparam` assignments with dot syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to define the local parameters inside of a generate statement. There are a couple of ways to go with this, you can either define your local params in an if-else fashion like so:

```
localparam FFT_XN_DATA_WIDTH = (CORE_TYPE=="DOPPLER_FFT_DO") ? 42 
                             : (CORE_TYPE=="DOPPLER_FFT_D1") ? 64
                             : 24;     // Equivalent to case "default"
localparam FFT_XK_DATA_WIDTH = (CORE_TYPE=="DOPPLER_FFT_DO") ? 66 
                             : (CORE_TYPE=="DOPPLER_FFT_D1") ? 66
                             : 24;     // Equivalent to case "default"
localparam FFT_LENGTH        = (CORE_TYPE=="DOPPLER_FFT_DO") ? 2048 
                             : (CORE_TYPE=="DOPPLER_FFT_D1") ? 512
                             : 256;     // Equivalent to case "default"
```

Or, if it gets too complicated, you can define a function that achieves the functionality, and call the function with the local params instantiation:

```
function automatic int get_xn_width(input string core_type); 
    if(core_type == "DOPPLER_FFT_DO")       return 42; 
    else if(core_type == "DOPPLER_FFT_DO")  return 64; 
    else                                    return 24; 
endfunction

// Define similar functions for the other local parameters 

module doppler_fft_cluster # (
  parameter CORE_TYPE = "DOPPLER_FFT_D0"
) (
  clk, rst_,
  i_tvalid, i_tdata, i_tready, i_tlast
  // and more ports
);
    // port definitions
-------------
    localparam FFT_XN_DATA_WIDTH = get_xn_width(CORE_TYPE);
    // Same for other localparams
-------------
    // Rest of module
endmodule
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error is you have defined the `localparam`s inside unnamed `begin/end` blocks. You need to give them a name to access them from outside.

```
module doppler_fft_cluster # (
  parameter CORE_TYPE = "DOPPLER_FFT_D0"
) (
  clk, rst_,
  i_tvalid, i_tdata, i_tready, i_tlast
  // and more ports
);
case (CORE_TYPE)
    "DOPPLER_FFT_D0": begin : FFT
      localparam XN_DATA_WIDTH = 42;
      localparam XK_DATA_WIDTH = 66;
      localparam LENGTH = 2048;
    end
    "DOPPLER_FFT_D1": begin : FFT
      localparam XN_DATA_WIDTH = 64;
      localparam XK_DATA_WIDTH = 66;
      localparam LENGTH = 512;
    end
endcase
input clk;
input rst_;
input  i_tvalid;
input  i_tdata;
output i_tready;
input  i_tlast;
input  [FFT.XN_DATA_WIDTH-1:0] i_tdata;  // Boom!

  initial $display("%m FFT.LENGTH = ", FFT.LENGTH);
endmodule

module top;
  doppler_fft_cluster #()                 D0(,,,,,);
  doppler_fft_cluster #("DOPPLER_FFT_D1") D1(,,,,,);
endmodule
```

Comment: What is the reason for SV requiring a named block in this context?

Comment: Because a begin/end block creates an independent scope/namespace where you can declare identifiers, and the same identifier name can appear in different scopes. You need the scope to be named to remove ambiguity if you want to hierarchically reference them. And not giving the block a name makes it explicitly that you don't want the identifiers reference from outside the block.

Comment: So the generate creates a new scope much like a module instance does.  Without a name for the new scope, there is no way to access the names/identifiers that exist the new scope.

Comment: I believe with any `begin`/`end` that is generated or in a procedural block, a new scope in an unnamed block only gets created if there are identifiers declared in that scope.